# Use a vector in filter() with group_by() data

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

I would like to filter (subset) some observations from a dataframe (A). However, I have to group the observations within the df, which I did with group_by. This gives me a total of 6660 groups. Now I would like to subset those observations which meet a certain range within each group. Therefore I created a dataframe (B), which holds the lower and upper boundary condition. Like the groups, this dataframe consists of 6660 observations.

```
NewDataFrame <-filter(A %>% group_by(a,b,c),which(d >= B$x && d <= B$y ))
```

A is the original df,
B holds the lower and upper boundary condition

Variations of the code with other functions I tried did not work either, except if I used fixed values instead of B$x and B$y.  Otherwise I typically end up with:

"longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Unfortunally, I found nothing in old questions regarding this topic. I am thankful for any help!

Here I tried to create some test Data. I did not create  A$b and A$c as they are only grouping conditions...

```
    a<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")
d<-rep(1:6,4)
A<-data.frame(a,d)

x<-c(3,5,1)
y<-c(6,6,3)
B<-data.frame(x,y)

a_new<-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C")
d_new<-c(3,4,5,6,5,6,1,2,3)
NewDataFrame<-data.frame(a_new,d_new)
```

Comment: It seems like you can do something like `A %>% group_by(a,b,c) %>% filter(between(d, lower, upper))`, where `lower` and `upper` can be calculated within that code. Can you post some data?

Comment: @AntoniosK Thank you for your answer. I tried this on the  data and ended up with :" Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: Expecting a single value: [extent=6660]..

Comment: I need to see your data and your ideal output. Maybe you can check this `library(dplyr);

mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, cyl) %>%
  filter(between(disp, 100, 150))` and how you can apply it to your case?

Comment: @AntoniosK Thanks again. The problem  still seems to be the vector of x and y...

Comment: You'll probably have to calculate them and add them as columns in your dataset, so you can use them...

Comment: the conditions x and y cannot be calculated from table A . And only fit to the grouped data. then it would work by a function, based on the columns ...